# Google Apps Script: Multiple recipients in GmailApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-for-education

Can I email multiple recipients through GmailApp.sendEmail()? I've tried storing the recipient addresses as an array, but it doesn't seem to send any of them.

Thanks!

Comment: All right, seems to have just been a delay in sending, maybe related to [this](http://mashable.com/2013/09/23/gmail-email-delays/?utm_campaign=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-Tech-Partial&utm_cid=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-Tech-Partial&utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=dlvr.it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can.

If you direct yourself towards the Google Apps Spreadsheet services, you can see under the Gmail method that there are advanced parameters.
[GmailApp Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29)

It can look something like this.

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message, {cc: "email1@email.com,email2@email.com"});
```

I never liked that way, and if I was sending to a varying number of people, and wanted to send them each an email instead of it being one big CC, the work around I found was this:

```
var emails = ["email1@email.com","email2@email.com","email3@email.com"];
for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emails[i], subject, message);
}
```

This way you can just simply edit the emails array by adding/subtracting an email and never having to change the actual code that sends the email.  Only downside is it sends out X number of emails based on how many addresses you have in the array (if you're worried about hitting the daily cap), but it works none the less.

Comment: By the way, you will want to add a comma between `message` and `{` for the fourth parameter option

Comment: I stored my recipient emails as an array, then simply did an array join to invoke GmailApp.sendEmail once instead of numerous times. `GmailApp.sendEmail(emails.join(', '), subject, message);`

Answer (score 6):

The recipient argument takes a string, so you can simply write your multiple recipients as a string with a comma in between:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail('first.last@example.com, your.friend@example.com', ...);
```

Should work. Note that they will all see each other as recipients.

Edit: I tried it and it works.

Comment: This doesn't work now. You can send an array tho.

Answer (score 0):

When I have multiple addresses, I just reference the list via a range.  The below script sample would send to 5 email addresses pulled from C2:C6 on the sheet/tab named Email.

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var emailRange = ss.getSheetByName("Email").getRange(2,3,5,1);
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
      Logger.log(emailAddress);
    var message = 'Message you wish to enter';
    var subject = 'Verbiage for Subject Line';
   GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message)
```