# Unable to send bulk mails using Appscripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to develop a program such that whenever someone submits a form, the contents of the form are to be mailed to ~100 users.

Since this content is generic, I want to send the mail to these 100 ppl together in one go in one email. I have saved these e-mail IDs as a row range, I can also save it in a single cell if reqd.

Is there any way I can send a single mail to them instead of running a loop? It is such a simple thing, but Google keeps throwing an error saying quota exceeded, whereas I have 500 remaining email quotas.

Comment: look at the comment from AjCodez at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968180/google-apps-script-multiple-recipients-in-gmailapp#18968309

Comment: From what you have shared it is impossible to tell. Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal-Reproducible-Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then edit your question so we can help you. Help us help you!